# how to cut a csv as parts for a condition

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv, split

I have a CSV which has the follwing data

```
time     t_count       state       hour
_____    ________      _____      _____
  1        10            2          1
  2        12            2          1
  3        30            2          1
  4        12            2          1
  1        9             3          1
  2        18            3          1
  6        27            3          1
  1        18            4          1
  2        30            4          1
  9        27            4          1
.......................................
......................................
  2        30            2          2
  8        18            2          2
  3        36            2          2
  3        6             3          2
  6        19            3          2
  8        28            3          2
  1        19            4          2
  2        36            4          2
  9        30            4          2
.....................................
.....................................
....................................
```

Likewise I have time and t_count for each state and each hour.I have state form 2 to 99 and hour from 1 to 23.So I need to split this CSV into  each CSV for each state and each hour as

```
 state_2_hour_1.csv
  1        10            2          1
  2        12            2          1
  3        30            2          1
  4        12            2          1



 state_3_hour_1.csv

  1        9             3          1
  2        18            3          1
  6        27            3          1
```

...

```
state_2_hour_2.csv
      2        30            2          2
      8        18            2          2
      3        36            2          2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try this awk command.

```
awk 'NR>2{filename="state_"$3"_hour_"$NF".csv"; print $0 > filename}' input.csv
```